# Can't modify 'updated_at' in my database after adding a column with a migration in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to add a new integer "id" column in a table of my database to map every row with an id. In order to do so, I am using a migration in Laravel 5.1. The run() function of the migration is exactly the following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('license_keys', function($table) {
        $table->integer('id_nuevo');
    });
}
```

The table I am trying to modify is set with default 'updated_at' and 'created_at' timestamps.

I execute the migration and the column is added correctly. I made sure to add the new column in the $fillable variable in my model. The next step in the process is to set the ids correctly, because that column is created with all 0s. In order to do so, I am using a Seeder with the following code:

```
public function run()
{
    $i=1;
    $licenses = LicenseKey::getEveryLicenseKey();
    foreach ($licenses as $license){
        $license->id_nuevo = $i;
        //$license->timestamps = false;
        $license->save();
        $i++;
    }

}
```

But the problem starts here. When I try to update any field of any row with the save() function it gives me the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                     
 SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136       Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (SQL: update `license_keys`   set `id_nuevo` = 1, `updated_at` = 2018-11-15 13:24:11   
 where `hash_key` = 0...0b)                                                                                                                                                     



  [PDOException]                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

But if I set the timestamps to false (commented line in the code), the operation succeeds. Even if I try to manually change the value of the 'updated_at' column in phpMyadmin, it gives me the same error. Can anybody help me with this problem?

The structure of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `license_keys` (
`hash_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`plan_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_nuevo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_credits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`max_models` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_model_categories` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_dictionaries` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_dictionary_entries` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_sentiment_models` int(11) NOT NULL,
`max_sentiment_entries` int(11) NOT NULL,
`current_credits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`current_requests` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`last_operation` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`total_credits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`total_requests` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`msg_pay_status` varchar(510) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`start_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`start_billing_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`expiration_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`update_operation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the query I'm trying to execute is:

```
update `license_keys` set `id_nuevo` = 1, `updated_at` = '2018-11-15 13:24:11' where `hash_key` = '0...0b'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the query you execute and the table structure?

Comment: Yes, for sure! I edited the post with that information

Answer (score 1):

Try your query without update_at, it will be written automatically

```
update `license_keys` set `id_nuevo` = 1 where `hash_key` = '0...0b'
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But the thing is that before the migration, the function save(), worked perfectly, and after, it returns that error. The entire code is full of calls to save(), and they wont work. I can just change the query. I must make that funtion work. But thanks anyway!